# Too Many Files Open error in java NIO

Tags: java, sockets

Hi I have created a socket and client program using java NIO.
My server and client are on different computers ,Server have LINUX OS and CLIENT have WINDOWS OS. Whenever I have created 1024 sockets on client my client machines supports but in server I got too many files open error.
So How to open 15000 sockets without any error in server.
Or is there any other way to connect with 15000 clients at the same time?

Thanks
Bapi

Answer (score 6):

Ok, questioning why he needs 15K sockets is a separate discussion.

The answer is that you are hitting the user's file descriptor limit.

Log with the user you will use in the listener and do $ulimit -n to see the current limit.

Most likely 1024.

Using root edit the file  `/etc/security/limits.conf`

and set ->

```
{username} soft nofile 65536
{username} hard nofile 65536
```

65536 is just a suggestion, you will need to figure that out from your app.

Log off, log in again and recheck with ulimit -n, to see it worked.

Your are probably going to need more than 15 fds for all that. Monitor your app with lsof.

Like this:

```
$lsof -p {pid}   <- lists all file descriptors
$lsof -p {pid}  | wc -l    <- count them
```

By the way, you might also hit the system wide fd limit, so you need to check it:

```
$cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

To increase that one, add this line to the /etc/sysctl.conf

```
#Maximum number of open FDs
fs.file-max = 65535
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to have 15000 sockets on one machine?  Anyway, look at [ulimit](http://www.ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) -n

Comment: Thanks Matthew Flaschen,
ulimit -n gives me 1024. What does it mean.
Also How can I connect to 15000 clients at the same time.
Thanks,
Bapi

Comment: man ulimit.

if you execute 

ulimit -n 20000 before starting the server, the process will be allowed to open more files.

Comment: (in the same shell /start script)

Comment: Thanks Karlp,
Can you please mention what is the maximum file that can be opened in linux OS. Does it support opening 200000 file?

Comment: If you want to find the system-wide limit, look at the special file /proc/sys/fs/file-max .  You can also modify that.  However, I concur you should not be modifying these limits without great reason.  Building out (more machines) is better and usually cheaper than building up (trying to make a single machine do more).

Comment: Often your OS has a hard limit you cannot easily increase beyond.  You are likely to have scalability problems if you have more than about 10K connections to one machine.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the scope of your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have 15,000 clients talking to your server (and possibly 200,000 in the future according to your comments) then I suspect you're going to have scalability problems servicing those clients once they're connected (if they connect).

I think you may need to step back and look at how you can architect your application and/or deployment to successfully achieve these sort of numbers.

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thanks for your info. Can you please guide me in the right direction for how to create more than 15000 connections without creating that much client

Comment: Not in the space of a comment field. I think you may have to start Googling, based on the required functionality of your application. Best of luck